# Calculate index of character in google doc, on 100th page, Same as how SAVE API call does

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-docs

[image]I have really struggled a lot on this problem. I want to find the character index in google docs which have 150 pages.

**What I want:**
exact character index of on the page text click,

**Reference:** What i saw Save API, gets that information somehow, you can check by following the below steps.

1. go to page 100th in a google document by scrolling.
2. open debugger and check SAVE API call after editing in the document.
3. Check the request body "ibi" property will give you the exact index.

I want to get that index on page text click.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, It is not possible for apps script to capture client side DOM events. Also, there is nothing in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document) about capturing selection from document. Though selection capture is possible both in Sheets and Slides.